# I keep getting this error in Swift. "Consecutive Declarations On A Line Must Be Separated By ';'"

Tags: ios, swift

Here is my code, any help is much appreciated thank you! This was written in Xcode in Swift. I keep getting the error that states "Consecutive Declarations On A Line Must Be Separated By ';'"

```
     import UIKit

class View Controller: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet var outputLabel: UILabel! = UILabel()

var currentCount : Int = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func addOneButton(sender: UIButton) {

    currentCount = currentCount + 1
    if(currentCount <= 1) {
        outputLabel.text = "The button has been clicked 1 time!"
    outputLabel.textColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
    }
    else {
    outputLabel.text = "The button has been clicked \(currentCount) number of times."
    outputLabel.textColor = UIColor.redColor()


        var Hello: UILabel! {
            if(currentCount >= 5) {
                outputLabel.text = "Don't Forget To Give A GOOD Rating! :D"
            outputLabel.textColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
            }
            else {
                outputLabel.text = "Nothing To See Here..."
                }
```

Comment: Which line do you get the error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you had an extra space between View and Controller in the class name and also a lot of missing closing parentheses.

Try this:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var outputLabel: UILabel! = UILabel()

    var currentCount : Int = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func addOneButton(sender: UIButton) {

        currentCount = currentCount + 1
        if(currentCount <= 1) {
            outputLabel.text = "The button has been clicked 1 time!"
            outputLabel.textColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
        }
        else {
            outputLabel.text = "The button has been clicked \(currentCount) number of times."
            outputLabel.textColor = UIColor.redColor()

            var Hello: UILabel! {
                if(currentCount >= 5) {
                    outputLabel.text = "Don't Forget To Give A GOOD Rating! :D"
                    outputLabel.textColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
                }
                else {
                    outputLabel.text = "Nothing To See Here..."
                }
                return outputLabel
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually it didn't work, got an error on the 4th to last line.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out. Please be sure to accept answers that are helpful to you. It's really appreciated.

Comment: Could you help me out again, theres still an error on the fourth to last line that says "Missing return in a function expected to return UILabel!"

Comment: I edited my answer to include a return of the `outputLabel`. Where did you find this code? I highly recommend that you try to understand the code that you are using before copy and pasting.

Comment: No problem. Good luck and keep at it. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0):

```
    var Hello: UILabel! {
```

This line looks wrong. Remove it.

*Edit*

There are also `}` missing at the end.
Correctly indenting your code will help spotting such errors a lot!

*Edit 2*

Oh and I guess you mean `class ViewController` instead of `class View Controller`.

Comment: I tried to remove that line, it created more errors. Also, thats the identification for a label with text so I didn't write that line Xcode does it for you. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: What is the purpose of `var Hello: UILabel! {`? The code doesn't make any sense at the moment. I'm surprised that Xcode even compiles it.

Comment: When I added a new label, I option dragged it to the executor to write the code for it, which I believe it was you are supposed to do.

Comment: Yes, but the code should be *outside* of any other methods, inside the `class ViewController: UIViewController { ... }` block. You dragged it inside a method.

Comment: Ahhhh still getting an error! "Missing return in a function expected to return UILabel!" But you're right I did make that mistake.

Comment: What's the current code now? Update your initial post.