# how to use objective-c category cocoapods in swift project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods, objective-c-category

I know how to use objective-c project as a pod in swift project. But I don't know how to use an objective-c category. I can D&D to use the category project, however I want to use it in cocoapod way for ease of updates.

my iOS-Bridging-Header.h

```
#import <FIR/FIR.h>
#import <NSDate-Escort/NSDate+Escort.h>
```

When I import the second file, the Xcode says:

```
'NSDate-Escort/NSDate-Escort.h' file not found
```

my Podfile

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'TimeMachine' do
  pod 'FIR.im', '~> 1.3.1'
  pod 'MGSwipeTableCell', '~> 1.5.1'
  pod 'XCGLogger', '~> 2.3'
  pod 'NSDate-Escort', '~>1.5.1'
end

target 'TimeMachineTests' do

end
```

I executed pod install, and the pods are installed correctly..

Comment: Any update on how to fix this?

Comment: @pa12 use #import <NSDate_Escort/NSDate+Escort.h>, although the folder name is "NSDate-Escort"

Comment: Thanks. Let me try your solution.

Answer (score 3):

Try using:

`use_frameworks!`    In the podfile 
and
`import NSDate-Escort`    in the swift file

Comment: Actually, I found that hyphens should be converted to underscores for it to work. E.g. use `import NSDate_Escort`

Answer (score 1):

After adding "use_frameworks!" the Objective-C code you're including as a dependency is packaged as a framework, instead of a static library.

Two options:

1. Don't use a bridging header file. Add i.e. `import XCGLogger` to every swift file you need.
2. Change bridging header imports from

`#import <FIR/FIR.h>`

to

`#import <FIR.h>`

Comment: I have tried to use "import NSDate-Escort" in my swift file, but it failed to say "Consecutive statements on a line must be seprarated by ;". I cannot import the framework. It works fine if it is NOT a objective-c category.

Comment: bet problem is not with import http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26132157/i-keep-getting-this-error-in-swift-consecutive-declarations-on-a-line-must-be

Answer (score 1):

I'm using use_frameworks! with Xcode 8 and noticed today that for some pods you have to use a _ instead of -.

This wouldn't work. Xcode gave said

> "Consecutive statements on a line must be seprarated by ;"

```
import UIView-FDCollapsibleConstraints
```

then after looking at my pods/products folder i noticed it was called UIView_FDCollapsibleConstraints

This worked for me

```
 import UIView_FDCollapsibleConstraints
```

Hope this helps someone, im not sure if this cocoapods or the pod im using that caused this.